# How to Get next monthyear(YYYYMM) by passing any monthyear(YYYYMM) in Java?

Tags: java, android

Example, I have a monthyear on String, like this:

```
202108
```

And I want to next month by passing above month in below format:

```
202109
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` can help you a lot.

```
    public static String getNextMonth(String s) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        try{
            cal.setTime(sdf.parse(s));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2021 is poor advice. See modern solution in [Answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68829522/642706).

Answer (score 5):

Java 8+ ⇒ `java.time.YearMonth`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create a formatter for the String format you are using
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM");
    // use it in order to parse the String to a YearMonth
    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse("202108", dtf);
    // add a month to have the next one
    YearMonth nextYearMonth = yearMonth.plusMonths(1);
    // and print it using the formatter
    System.out.println(nextYearMonth.format(dtf));
}
```

Output:

```
202109
```

If you want it as a method/function, then try something like

```
public static String getYearMonthAfter(String month) {
    // create a formatter for the String format you are using
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM");
    // use it in order to parse the String to a YearMonth
    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(month, dtf);
    // add a month to have the next one
    YearMonth nextYearMonth = yearMonth.plusMonths(1);
    // and return the resulting String by means of the formatter
    return nextYearMonth.format(dtf);
}
```

Comment: For Java 6 and 7, this same `YearMonth` functionality is available by adding the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add` function in Calendar class to add month

```
public String getNextMonth(String time){

   DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
   Date dt = sdf.parse(time);
  
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.setTime(dt);
   c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  //adding a month 

   String req_date = sdf.format(c.getTime());

   return req_date;

}
```